# RecyclerView горизонтальная прокрутка при вертикальном LinearLayoutManager

Tags: android, recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

У меня есть `RecyclerView` который отображает вертикальный список, каждая строка уходит за пределы экрана и мне нужно чтобы была горизонтальная прокрутка. Получается это реализовать, только если поместить `RecyclerView` в `HorizontalSrollView`, но это костыль.

Как реализовать прокрутку внутри ресайкла чтобы можно было прокручивать layout горизонтально без помещения ресайкла в HorizontalSrollView?

[image: SCROLL]

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rvMain"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Вы отображаете список в списке?(горизонтальный в каждом элементе вертикального)
Или же у Вас просто не хватает места на экране, и хотите чтобы была прокрутка?

Немного не понятен этот момент

Comment: Не хватает места на экране. У меня горизонтальный LinearLayout итем с ячейками TextView.